# Why is there no way to specify install options for binaries in ebuilds?

Tags: gentoo, ebuild

The Gentoo's ebuild mecanism comes with several built-in eclasses/commands to manage (amongst others) libraries, binaries, executables, etc... Some of them are really useful to work at installation phase, like setting permissions, modifying the default installation directory, etc...

About library installation, the [ebuild documentation](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/eclass-reference/ebuild/index.html#lbAQ) says :

> **dolib  [list of more libraries]**
>
> Installs a library or a list of libraries into DESTTREE/lib. Creates all necessary dirs.
>
> **libopts [options for install(1)]**
>
> Can be used to define options for the install function used in the dolib functions. The default is -m0644.

The same is available for "executables": **exeopts** works with **doexe**.

### Question

The thing I really don't understand is that why **dobin** and **dosbin** exist but not **binopts** and **sbinopts**?

Is it possible have **libopts** or **exeopts** equivalents for **dobin** and **dosbin**, to manage permissions at installation phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `dobin` and `dosbin` are special cases of `doexe`, which have pre-defined options; if you need special permissions (e.g. suid) you can use `doexe` as needed.

Effectively `(/usr)/bin` and `(/usr)/sbin` should be executable to all users, unless something special (like limiting access to a group that has access to the hardware) is needed.

(I would probably be in favour of removing `libopts` too, but that's a different story, I guess.)